# How to make this banner slider to fit the browser height?

Tags: javascript, css

I googled for 2 days trying to understand how the auto height fit works, I think I understand in how to make a background fits the browser, but with [this](http://www.interpixel.hk/) banner slider, I don't have a clue.

Could someone please enlighten me on where should I look for/start? Should it be a `CSS` or `JS`?

I'm very new to `HTML5/CSS3`, `Wordpress` gave me a very easy environment to start a website, but I just barely know how to modify a website other than a plugin.

It would be very cool if the slider section to fit like this one below
[image: wanted result]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you will get many down votes here, please check the tutorial on how to ask questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I accepted your correction.The thread did not allow me to attach the image here, glad that you helped.

Answer (score 0):

This should set the image/album you have on the homepage to be the height and width of the browser, tweak some of the CSS and it should line up with the Sidebar perfectly like you wanted.

```
  img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        width: auto\9;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice MrShedford. I tried to locate it with its id #grid-1024, made the following to the style.css and it still won't work. Maybe I located a wrong id?
#grid-1024 {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        width: auto\9;
}

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the image that fits the browser height regardless of any display then you can use 'vh' unit from [this css units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) page.

vh means viewport height[viewport = the browser window size.], and 1vh = 1% of the height of viewport, so in your case you can use 100vh for image like this:

```
img{
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kishan93/4ucxrwqz/)  for the same.

Remember that you need high-resolution images and those images will not look good on mobile devices.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Kishan. I tried to locate it with its id #grid-1024, made the following to the style.css and it still won't work. Maybe I located a wrong id?
#grid-1024 {
  height: 100vh;
}
I installed a 'Wordpress' plugin called 'The Grid' and it seems different then just make the background image to fit the height.

Comment: Maybe some other styles on your page is controlling the height with more specific selector, to solve this just add '!important' attribute, like this `#grid-1024{
  height: 100vh !important;
}`